# To build a RSS Reader

Tags: redis

If I want to build an RSS reader then inserting all feeds in a MySQL would be too heavy for the DB server, CPU intensive.

So would having a Redis or cassandra, MySQL server with Apache help in the reducing the load on mysql server?

Comment: redis is not magic bullet, you know.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I am aware, redis would come to push/pull feeds rather than have the db do it.

Comment: Modern databases are faster than you think.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev What I want to do cannot be done on a mysql server or can it be which is why I posted this question.

Comment: I say, go ahead and use mysql alone. If you have problems - throw redis in. No need to overcomplicate from the start.

Comment: That is a lot of cron job threads.

Comment: And how is it different with redis?

Comment: select each feed title from the db, run, insert back for mysql.

Comment: Can you explain your problem more? How would your RSS reader work? How much data would you save? How fast would you be expecting updates? How many clients would you have? Off hand, doing something like batch writes to MySQL from Redis + Pub/Sub for currently connected clients sounds pretty good to me, but this really depends on your use case. Please give us more information.

Comment: @Eli Starting off with 10K users and considering on average 40 feeds/user.  I would save all unread posts.  Are all read posts deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, but it will add complexity.

Long answer: If MySQL isn't fast enough for you (and I would first verify that this is, in fact, the case before adding the complexity of Redis), you could throw some of the more frequent update/insert load onto Redis. A few ways to do this (you don't have to do everything here, but each thing will help with your load):

1. **Have a Redis pub/sub channel for each user.** Publish directly to it whenever something is added to a user's feed. Have the RSS client subscribe to this channel, so if a user has his or her RSS reader open, they should just be subscribed to their pub/sub channel for updates, and never read from MySQL.
2. **Batch insert into MySQL**: If you have heavy write volume, don't endure the network traffic and locking/unlocking and query overhead of inserting into MySQL every time something new should be added to the feed. Instead, save all new items in a per-user cache. Then empty the cache and do a bulk write every n seconds. Set n as high as needed for your use case.
3. **Cache feeds per user**: If your read volume is very high despite #1, cache in Redis the last n items per user for m seconds (set n and m as befits your use case). Best way to cache these is most likely as a string. Use a list, if for some reason you need more dynamic access. Users should then read from MySQL only if their cache is unavailable.